# How do I Escape PHP inside of a echo function?

Tags: php

What I have is this:

```
function add_email_form () {

 echo "<form class=\"email-me-form\" id=\"initialize\" action=\"<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>\" method=\"post\" name=\"contact_me\">\n";

}
```

How do I make this syntactically correct?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use double quotes unless you need to. Use single quotes, '. That way, you don't have to escape anything except control characters like the \n, and in that case, do drop to double quotes. So the above would be:

```
echo '<form class="email-me-form" id="intialize" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"
      method="post" name="contact_me">'."\n";
```

(newline added to I don't cause a horizontal scrollbar)
You don't need to do htmlspecialchars() looks like what you want.

You don't need to (and in fact, cannot) call "`<?php echo?>`" inside a PHP statement. Only when you're outside of PHP does that work. In this case, just concatenate with `.`.

And as stated in the comments, you should quote array keys when they're strings, as otherwise PHP will throw a warning and could potentially be confused.

Comment: not quoting PHP_SELF will result in a warning if they are turned on.

Comment: For some reason I assumed that was a constant, but you're right, it's a string key and needs to be quoted. Edited.

Comment: This is the way you should do it. I always found quoting confusing. But really use single-quotes whereever you can and only double quotes when you need to substitute variables or special characters, e.g. "\n"

Comment: I also prefer to use single quotes and concatenation because I don't want to have to remember all the rules for when $variables are evaluated when using them inside double quotes, or having to deal with array keys, or variable variables, or object properties, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like so:

```
echo "<form class=\"email-me-form\" id=\"initialize\" action=\"",
  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),
  "\" method=\"post\" name=\"contact_me\">\n";
```

Comment: This will fail if the user has done `define('PHP_SELF', 'something')`. PHP will be polite and assume you meant `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, but spit out warnings if you've got those enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_email_form () {
    echo "<form class=\"email-me-form\" id=\"initialize\" action=\"" . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] . "\" method=\"post\" name=\"contact_me\">\n";
}
```